# Include plugins as binary vs. source files in Android project?

Tags: android, plugins, binaryfiles

I have many plugins (and open source libraries) to include in an Android app. Assuming I have both binary and source files at hand, which one of the following options should I choose to keep my project clean, fast, and performance-and-maintenance-oriented?

1. Include plugins/libraries as binary files under `PROJECT_ROOT/bin/`
2. Include plugins/libraries as source files under `PROJECT_ROOT/MY_PLUGIN_NAME/` or `PROJECT_ROOT/src/com.mypluginname/`

What would be the drawbacks of choosing one option over the other?

Comment: if you don't want to modify and use library as it was, then plugin in binary is good though it will not compiled by Android OS every time you run your application. This will save your compilation time. otherwise source.

Comment: @ChintanRathod I appreciate your input. By using Proguard, we can eliminate unused source codes and condense the size of the application (therefore enhancing performance). For quite often times, I end up using only small part of the plugins/libraries. So, Proguard will most likely modify the codes. I am not using a supercomputer to develop my application, but I'd tradeoff reasonable amount of delay during compilation time for any magnitude of performance enhancement for release version.